# Bootstrap does not stretch a dropdown control to column definition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.2

The label uses all its size (6 columns wide)

The dropdown control does not use the parent size of 6 columns.

I want that the dropdown stretches its width to the width of the parent container, how can I do that with bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="buttondropdown">
          Schoolclass code color
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
         <!-- subject color -->
         <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="activeStep.schoolclassCodeColorsIsOpen"> 
             <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled" style="background: {{activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor}}">
                  {{activeStep.schoolclassCode()}}  <span  class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li ng-repeat="color in activeStep.schoolclassCodeColors">
                      <a style="background: {{color}}" ng-click="activeStep.setSchoolclassCodeColor(color)">{{activeStep.schoolclassCode()}}</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the width of the btn or the menu? Why not add a full width col to the `dropdown-menu` __ http://www.bootply.com/0yB6R9THdC

Comment: Just the width of the btn. The button with the dropdown directive on it should have the full width of col-md-6.